# What pain point does Intelligent Children Design Pattern solve?

Tags: design-patterns

In absence of this pattern, `downcasting` is needed in the derived classes. My question is does this pattern solve only the problem of `downcasting`? And why is `downcasting` bad compared to the alternative offered by Intelligent Childrean Design Pattern?

Comment: Cross-posted from here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302759/what-pain-point-does-intelligent-children-design-pattern-solve

Answer (score 3):

> My question is does this pattern solve only the problem of
>   downcasting?

Yes. It's a non-issue in dynamically-typed languages. It's specifically oriented around issues that arise in statically-typed languages with relationships that want to form between dual hierarchies, and specifically to avoid the need for a downcast.

> And why is downcasting bad compared to the alternative offered by
>   Intelligent Childrean Design Pattern?

There's lot of reasons why downcasting is kind of frowned upon. For a start, it kind of x-rays the type system (as is the general case with any form of explicit cast). Providing a virtual method in its place might seem like a loophole but it does establish a formal interface that's far less prone to be misused than an explicit, low-level cast reinterpreting bits and bytes. In a rare event, a downcast might be the right tool for the job, but it's a heavy-handed tool and when there's a safer alternative, it's typically better.

With `dynamic_casts` you get back some safety, but with the need for RTTI (which is sometimes not always a luxury available in some tight contexts). And it's still not working with the constrained kind of public interface available for a type, but rather "around" it (ex: there's no strong compile-time enforcement of what types are available as a legit target type to cast a source type). It throws exceptions for references and returns null for pointers which can be kind of trippy behavior.

With a virtual method, you can use that statically-typed language and compiler and make it work for you, spotting more human errors in the process. You can also add instrumentation and whatever you like to a virtual method, whereas you're kind of helpless with a cast.

Mostly it's just safer to make it an explicit part of an interface, and also a little more clear as to what legitimate behavior is provided by a data type (or more appropriately, interface). Some of this is "aesthetic", but there are some definite benefits to avoiding the downcast.